# template tag is showing duplicate items in template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I am building a Blog App and I built a `template tag` to `sort posts by likes`. Template tag I working fine, But when I sort `by likes` then it is showing duplicate items according to likes. I mean, If a post got 3 likes then it is showing that post thee times.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
```

template_tags.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def sort(queryset, order):
    return queryset.order_by(order)
```

views.py

```
def posts(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'posts.html', context)
```

posts.html

```
{% load template_tags %}

{% block content %}


{% for post in posts|sort:'likes' %}

{{post.title}}

{% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

I have also tried by using `distinct()` in both `template_tags.py` and `views.py` but it is making no effect on query.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work to get the ordering you want from the view

```
from django.db.models import Count


def posts(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(
        user=request.user
    ).annotate(
        count_likes=Count('likes')
    ).order_by('count_likes').distinct()

    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'posts.html', context)
```

Your `sort` filter is not useful when you need to sort by an annotation. I'm not sure the filter is useful at all, the ordering should be done in the view

Comment: Thanks for Answer. I know this can work But I will filter many queries through `template tag` and if I create every query like this then it will about 12-15 queries in views.py (It will make effect on `app`'s speed and performance). That's why I decided to create a template tag. So I can sort without using tens of queries.

Comment: So, if I use about `12-15` queries only for ordering the model's instances , Won't make effect on speed and performance ?

Comment: Can you give an example template and view where you have 12+ queries and you order them in the template? I'm not sure why you would order querysets in the template  and not the view

Comment: If I don't use `template tag` then i will have to make them after an hour. And You can guess all of them are just like this query you suggested But `Just model difference`

Comment: @Van that does not make sense, you say doing it in the template tag is better for performance? How?? Regardless of where you make a query (template / view) the server needs to execute it, correct? Also if you don't know that yet querysets are _lazy_ i.e. the query won't actually be executed until it's results are needed.

Comment: I cannot say that it is obvious bad for performance, But I thought it will. Did I thought wrong, about that multiple query in view for ordering is bad ?

Comment: @Van it's hard to say without seeing your view and queries but where the ordering is applied will not make a difference, the same queries will be run